# the meaning of lightweighted object

Tags: programming-languages

Please, gurus, give me a detailed explanation of, in the Object-Oriented programming world, what is lightweight object? And in other computer science fields, what does lightweight means then? Is lightweight a design pattern? Is lightweight good, is bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many meanings for lightweight, but normally it means the object which has less amount of data or which process less amount of data. Sometimes a thread is called as a lightweight process as it does a less things than a process do. Its processing is also fast than the process. A lightweight object is one which has less amount members and which are of basic types (int, float) as member variables. A light function is the one which does very less things compared to others. Normally these are inline functions. (in C context).
There is no such patterns as lightweight pattern. But Normally the systems should be consists of lightweight objects so that the maintaining those objects could be easy.
The advantages are simple debugging, maintenance and easy understanding of code. The disadvantage could be lots of objects.
There is no lightweight pattern as such but the term is fairly used in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight *X* tend to be used in the case where we have a somewhat well known structure *X*. Lightweight *X* is then a version of *X* using fewer resources in some way or the other - or is subtly different from *X* in some way.

The term, as is the case for most computer science, is not well-defined and is loosely used.

Comment: It is rather hard to give a good answer to a question which defined on the vague term of "lightweight". In Erlang a process is a "lightweight process" in the sense it is not a kernel thread. It is a good thing. But I have seen the term used for so many different things that I doubt anything meaningful will come out of trying to attach specific meaning to it now.